# Java weird NullPointExeption

Tags: java

Hey i am making a game in java and while loading the tilesheet I get a weird error and i cant fin out why.

```
public class TileSheetLoader {

BufferedImage tileSheet;

int width;
int height;
int rows;
int cols;
public BufferedImage[] tiles;

public void loader(int width, int height, int rows, int cols)
{
    try
    {
         ImageIO.read(new File("gfx/tileSheet.png"));
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Couldent load tileSheet.png");}
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.tiles = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            tiles[(i * cols) + j] = tileSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
            System.out.println("loaded tile");
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the code of the class.
I get the NullPointException on this line

```
tiles[(i * cols) + j] = tileSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
```

this is where i call the methode.

```
tilesheetloader.loader(96, 32, 1, 3);
```

already a big thanks for the people who took the time to read.

Comment: Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't allocate memory for `tileSheet`.

**Remember**: complex data types must be allocated with `new`.

I think you wanted to do this, but forgot to capture the return of `ImageIO.read()`:

```
tileSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("gfx/tileSheet.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks alot i feel kind of stupid now, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`tileSheet` is never instantiated with `new` keyword so it is null, and you are calling a method on a null value... thus NPE

probably what you wanted to do is stuff `ImageIO.read()` into `tileSheet`... once you put the return value of `ImageIO.read()` into `tileSheet`, it is not longer null, and you can call a method on the object